# Log a full request URL in IIS

Tags: iis

I'm using IIS8 on my Windows 8 development machine.  I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 WebAPI-based application, which interfaces with 3rd party servers.

One of these servers (Kaltura content management system) sends a notification which I just can't "catch" with my routing and/or controllers.  I'm trying to log the full request's URL on IIS to investigate it's syntax.

I've installed IIS Advanced Logging and configured it to log the all available fields (other than performance counters), but the logs does not contain the URL or the request's contents (a form).

My question is, is it possible to log the full URL in IIS?

Answer (score 1):

There is no default way to log all form fields. Logging everything would make log files go huge very quickly. If there was a way to log everything that would mean logging viewstate and all post fields (what if you’re uploading a 20MB file).

If you want to support something like this you would have to create a custom handler or do it in the website code itself (for example in master page so you don’t have to add logging code to every page).

Comment: Thanks George.  I understand your reasoning but I think it doesn't apply to development.  Moreover, the request I'm dealing with it is sent by a single peer server, from which the traffic is insignificant.
I've turned to IIS logs only after I've exhausted any "website code" resources I'm aware of.